manifest.json for Chrome extension: How to mach Youtube Video URL
I am developing an extension for Chrome.
The extension should work when a video is started in Youtube.
The wildcard for Youtube videos is :
https://www.youtube.com/watch* 

Therefore I have created the following manifest.json, which does not work, i.e. content.js is not executed when a video is started:
"content_scripts": [{
      "matches": [ "https://www.youtube.com/watch*" ],
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "all_frames": true,
      "run_at": "document_end"
}]

The following manifest.json works:
If www.youtube.com/* is entered as a match then content.cs is started, but this not what I need:
"content_scripts": [{
      "matches": [ "https://www.youtube.com/*" ],
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "all_frames": true,
      "run_at": "document_end"
  }]

How can I ensure that content.js only starts when a video is displayed, i.e. a URL https://www.youtube.com/watch* has been called up?
According to the information I have found it should be possible to use a wildcard URL as I have tried.
I have used some variants of the wildcard with “watch*” but without success, e.g. https://*.youtube.com/watch?v*
I am using the latest version 3.0 of manifest.json so older similar issues have not helped me.
